# How to add new permission requires only on Android 13?

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, android-13

I would like to add this permission from documentation on `Android 13`.

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission#new-apps

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

Could I simply add this to manifest or it could make some problems on previous versions like Android 10, 11, 12?

How to add this to be 100% sure everything will work fine with previous versions.

EDIT:
Like this manifest?

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"
        android:required="false"
        android:minSdkVersion="33" />
```

and in `mainActivity`

```
    private fun checkPermissions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            } else {
                requestPermission.launch(android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As far as I know older Android versions should simply ignore permissions they don't know.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a check "if" on based of Android OS version , like if is android 13 then get this permission otherwise dont take it. because other version dont need this permission ,

Comment: check my comment