# Why do I get ."POST_NOTIFICATIONS not found" when adapting to Android 13?

Tags: android

Build error: “: Symbol Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS not found“

build.gradle(:app)

```
compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode currentVersionCode
        versionName = currentVersionName}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

There is also an error message: “Error: Symbol Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU not found”
[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on? Please help me. Thank you.

I tried “Clean Project“ 、“Rebuild Project”、“Invalidate Caches" many times, but doesn't work

Comment: You should add `minSdkVersion` property like shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76365292/150978

Comment: Thank you ,but I think "Error: Symbol Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU not found " should not appear when I modified “compileSdkVersion 33“

Comment: I solved the problem, I updated gradle to 6.7.1/4.2.0 . It’s unbelievable, but it’s solved like this